# JQuery selectors and val() or text() appear to fail when element html replaced on edit in place elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to switch display elements to input elements so that I can let the user update data without refreshing the page.

Everything work fine except this code

```
 //* values*/
        var customernameval =  customername.attr('value');
        var customerphoneval =  customerphone.attr('value');
        var customerfaxval =  customerfax.attr('value');
        var customeremailval =  customeremail.attr('value');
```

I tried  val() and text(),  but they didn't work either!.

How can I get the value from the input so I can send it  using ajax!

```
/*Edit customer details*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#edit_customer_info',function(){
        var shipmentid = $(this).attr('value1');

        /*selectors*/
        var customername =  $('#edit_customer_name'+shipmentid);
        var customerphone =  $('#edit_customer_phone'+shipmentid);
        var customerfax =  $('#edit_customer_fax'+shipmentid);
        var customeremail =  $('#edit_customer_email'+shipmentid);
        var Update =  $('#update_customer_info');


        //* values*/
        var customernameval =  customername.text();
        var customerphoneval =  customerphone.text();
        var customerfaxval =  customerfax.text();
        var customeremailval =  customeremail.text();

        /*remove edit button*/
        $(this).css('display','none');
        /*show update button*/
        Update.css('display','inline');

        /*append input text into the field*/
        customername.html("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_name"+shipmentid+"' value='"+customernameval+"'>");
        customerphone.html("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_phone"+shipmentid+"' value='"+customerphoneval+"'>");
        customerfax.html("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_fax"+shipmentid+"' value='"+customerfaxval+"'>");
        customeremail.html("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_email"+shipmentid+"'  value='"+customeremailval+"'>");
    });

    //update customer data
    $(document).on('click','#update_customer_info',function(){
        var shipmentid = $(this).attr('value1');

        /*selectors*/
        var customername =  $('#edit_customer_name'+shipmentid);
        var customerphone =  $('#edit_customer_phone'+shipmentid);
        var customerfax =  $('#edit_customer_fax'+shipmentid);
        var customeremail =  $('#edit_customer_email'+shipmentid);

        //* values*/
        var customernameval =  customername.attr('value');
        var customerphoneval =  customerphone.attr('value');
        var customerfaxval =  customerfax.attr('value');
        var customeremailval =  customeremail.attr('value');

        alert(customernameval);
        /*append input text into the field*/
        customername.html(customernameval);
        customerphone.html(customerphoneval);
        customerfax.html(customerfaxval);
        customeremail.html(customeremailval);

    });
});
```

Comment: After your line 'var customername =  $('#edit_customer_name'+shipmentid);' add console.log('customername  count=' + customername.length). You are looking for 1. This is to confirm you don't have mutliple elements with customername id. Let me know.

Comment: I got  "customername count=1"

Comment: Ok - could you try it just before the alert. The idea is that when a simple jquery command like .val() fails then the first thing to check is your assumptions that (a) there is an element with the specified id, and (b) there are not multiple elements with the specified id. To check either (a) use the length attribute of the jquery object you got via the selector, or (b) hit F12 and inspect the elements and search (ctrl-F) for the expected element id. If the answer is 1 then your assumptions are correct and there is only one element so the issue must be something else. But it rarely is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is with the way you put the input boxes into the document. You are using

```
customername.html("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_name"+shipmentid+"' value='"+customernameval+"'>");
```

Assuming you start with

```
<div id="edit_customer_name1234">I am customer 1234</div>
```

Then your code this will give you...

```
<div id="edit_customer_name1234">
    <input type="text" id="edit_customer_name1234" value="I am customer 1234"/>
</div>
```

As you can see you have 2 elements with id = edit_customer_name1234

Solution: Use .replaceWith()

```
customername.replaceWith("<input type='text' id='edit_customer_name"+shipmentid+"' value='"+customernameval+"'>");
```

Docs [here at jquery](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

Alternatively, just change the id's on the input boxes to be different to the orignial display elements. So where you have

```
    <input type="text" id="edit_customer_name1234" value="I am customer
```

switch to

```
    <input type="text" id="input_customer_name1234" value="I am customer
```

And of course change your selectis in the second block to follow.

Comment: Thanksss. replaceWith  did it.  I have seen  it before.  the code works  now

Comment: No worries - have done this exact thing myself. Lost me hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of the inputs not existing at the time the DOM is loaded.  So what you need to do is change on the `$(document).on('click',`... section as follows:

```
//update customer data
    $(document).on('click','#update_customer_info',function(event){
        if ($(event.target).prop('id') === 'edit_customer_name') {
            var shipmentid = $(event.target).attr('value');
            var customername =  $('#edit_customer_name'+shipmentid);
        }
    ...
    });
```

for each field.  In this way, the element id is verified through bubbling.

From the [jQuery manual](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

...Consider what happens when we add a new anchor after having already bound the above listener:

```
// Add a new element on to our existing list

    $( "#list" ).append( "<li><a href='http://newdomain.com'>Item #5</a></li>" );
```

**If we were to click our newly added item, nothing would happen.** This is because of the directly bound event handler that we attached previously. Direct events are only attached to elements at the time the .on() method is called. In this case, since our new anchor did not exist when .on() was called, it does not get the event handler.

Comment: You could be right but out of interest how do you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, the OP is `/*append input text into the field*/` in the code listed.

Comment: OK but I read it as he has 2 buttons '#edit_customer_info' is clicked to expose the inputs then '#update_customer_info' is clicked to start some save process. There is an alert in the second which is where I assume the issue is. Since the second event is not fired until after the first (assumed) then the elements would be present. Or am I wrong? If so why?

Comment: It is a bit hard to tell without the starting HTML.  But the elements are created in the `edit` section.  We can assume only one element for an existing id (HTML rules).  It is confusing because `edit` and `update` are basically synonyms.  Regardless, even if the update event is fired after the edit event, the elements would not be part of the original DOM.  The browser doesn't exactly know that they exist, unless they are part of the original page loading.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, I added a quote from the jQuery man page to the answer.

Comment: The second alert fires, but I get  'undefined' value  when I use .attr('value1'). Anyway thank you but it didn't work.

Comment: Its credible but not correct I think. The only 'on' binding here is to the buttons (not included so I am assuming).

Comment: @jack, not sure where the `value1` came from, but that is not a attribute of the element.  Try `value` instead. I modified the answer.

Comment: @jack have a look at my answer below. Did you put the console.log in place ?

Comment: I mean value.  yeah I get "customername count=1"

Comment: @jack, it is very hard to tell without knowing your initial HTML.  Can you edit your original question with a snippet of what it is loaded, showing the relevant customer lines?

Comment: @Sablefoste - I think your answer is no quite right. The issue was the OP was duplicating the element id's in the html replacement. He thought html(new element) would replace the outer html of the element.  Overall it was probably a cut & paste oversight on the element id's as he developed the code. Nothing as sophisticated as your proposal.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, you must be right, the OP accepted your answer!  I hope this might help someone else who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var customernameval  = document.getElementById("edit_customer_name").value;
var customerphoneval = document.getElementById("edit_customer_phone").value;
var customerfaxval   = document.getElementById("edit_customer_fax").value;
var customeremailval = document.getElementById("edit_customer_email").value;
```

Comment: Far as I can see the OP is already getting those values via jquery selectors. Plus you overlooked the the element id's have a concatenated shipmentid. Without any explanation your answer seems to be of little value to the OP's need.

Comment: Please add at least a minimal description how this would solve the problem, rather than a code-only answer.